# redux Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am trying to implement redux in this component but I get the following error how could I do this?

the error it shows me is the following:

Uncaught Invariant Violation: Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a , or pass a custom React context provider to  and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options.

I know it is possible to do it this way but I don't want to inject the store into the component

store.dispatch(doResetStore());

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { Switch, Route, BrowserRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
import environment from '../../commons/enviroment.const';
import Loader from '../loader/Loader';
import {connect} from "react-redux";
import store from '../../store/store';
import { routes as routesConst, context } from '../../commons/routes/routes.const';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import MandateConsulting from '../mandate-consulting/MandateConsulting';
import { doResetStore } from '../../store/config/actions/actions';

class App extends Component {

  componentWillMount(){
      this.props.doResetStore();
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <BrowserRouter basename={context()}>
            <div id={environment.appName} className="ui-kit-reset">
              <Loader />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path={routesConst.etd} component={MandateConsulting} />
                <Route exact path={routesConst.default} component={MandateConsulting} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}

App.propTypes = {
    reset: PropTypes.any,
    doResetStore: PropTypes.any,
};

export const mapStateToProps = state => ({
    reset: state.config.reset
});

export const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    doResetStore: () => dispatch(doResetStore()),
});


export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your `App` component to be connected to the redux store, you need to wrap `App` component with `<Provider>`.

For example - It can be done with the parent component of `App` i.e. `index.js`:

**index.js**

```js
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

**App component**

```js
...
render() {
    return (
        <BrowserRouter basename={context()}>
            <div id={environment.appName} className="ui-kit-reset">
              <Loader />
              <Switch>
                <Route exact path={routesConst.etd} component={MandateConsulting} />
                <Route exact path={routesConst.default} component={MandateConsulting} />
              </Switch>
            </div>
        </BrowserRouter>
    );
  }
...
```